# Непонятного вида вызов np.array() в вызове функции кусочно-линейной регрессии

Tags: python, numpy

Start by preparing your data as list-likes of timestamps (independent variables) and values (dependent variables).

```py
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(10)
v = np.array(
    [2*i for i in range(5)] +
    [10-i for i in range(5, 10)]
) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
```

Данный код готовит данные для функции кусочно-линейной регрессии. Взят [отсюда](https://github.com/DataDog/piecewise), [вот](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/engineering/piecewise-regression/) описание функции.
Я новичек в `numpy`, не могу понять, что получится если сложить два списка внутри вызова функции `array`. Функция `np.random.normal`, я так понял берёт 10 семплов стандартного распределения и поэлементно складывает их с той хренью, что внутри вызова `array`. Внутри него, как я понял, создаются два списка `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]` и `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. Но я не могу найти в гугле, что будет, если использовать эти два списка внутри вызова `array` с использованием оператора `+`. Подскажите, что тут к чему.

Далее идёт следующее

> Now, you're ready to import the piecewise() function and fit a piecewise linear regression.

```
from piecewise import piecewise

model = piecewise(t, v)
```

> model is a FittedModel object. If you are at a shell, you can print the object to see the fitted segments domains and regression coefficients.

```
>>> model
FittedModel with segments:
* FittedSegment(start_t=0, end_t=5, coeffs=(-0.8576123780622642, 2.224791099812951))
* FittedSegment(start_t=5, end_t=9, coeffs=(10.975487672814133, -1.0722348284390741))
```

Здесь для сегментов графика из двух линейных уравнений вида y=kx+b вроде передаются две пары из смещения графика по оси y (b) и коэфициент наклона (k). Я ничего не перепутал?
Далее

> To see a plot, instead of getting a FittedModel, use piecewise_plot(). You may also use an existing FittedModel.

```
from piecewise import piecewise_plot

# using an existing FittedModel
piecewise_plot(t, v, model=model)

# fitting a model on the fly
piecewise_plot(t, v)
```

[Вот выводимый график](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataDog/piecewise/master/img/example_regression.png)
В этой части ничего не понятного нет, но он пригодится для понимания предыдущей части про смещение и коэффициент.

Comment: эти две списка просто объединятся и получится `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: Так ведь неважно же, где вы списки складываете. Это фича самого питона, что складываемые списки конкатенируются. А куда они потом передаются аргументами - это совершенно неважно, `np.array` про это ничего не знает, он получает результат этого сложения - то есть объединённый список.

Comment: То-есть внутри array была конкатенация, а вне - поэлементное сложение? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Я, кстати, заметил, что забыл добавить абзац перед кодом. С его учётом Получается что t - это X'ы функции [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], а v -Y'и функции [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], со слегка рандомизированные с помощью np.random.normal?

Comment: не важно где вы будете складывать списки, всегда будет конкатенация

Comment: Danis, эээ... a почему здесь https://datascienceparichay.com/article/numpy-elementwise-sum-two-arrays/ написано обратное? Смотрите абзац "Add two 1d arrays elementwise" В конце концов на графике на гитхабе там десять дата-поинтов а не двадцать...

Comment: @ЭдуардПавлов Внутри там списки питона складываются, а снаружи уже складываются массивы `numpy.array`, исходить нужно из этого )  Списки питона конкатенируются, а для `numpy` сложение поэлементное, да. Ну и да, обычно за счёт `np.random` либо генерируют полностью случайные данные, либо делают случайные отклонения от каких-то регулярных данных, добавляя результат `np.random` к результату вычислений какой-нибудь функции, как и сделано в данном случае.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо большое за разъяснения) Осталось понять, правильно ли я понял вывод результата функции (обновлено).

Comment: Ну да, всё правильно поняли. Можете просто попробовать подставить эти числа в формулу и посчитать значения на нескольких точках. Можете даже в уме, глядя на график это сделать, округлив значения до целых величин. Очень полезно делать такой "sanity check", проверяя, что ситуация "похожа на правду". Но вообще если у вас дополнительные вопросы, не связанные с основным вопросом. то задавайте их в новом вопросе, такие правила.

Comment: Спасибо, ещё раз, за сим тема закрыта)